# Get all sold products combinations quantities in prestashop

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Im trying to make a query in Prestashop SQL Manager, that will return all sold combinations quantities (In example: Dress XL - 200). I end up with

```
SELECT P.reference as SKU, 
PL.`name` as Product_Name, 
COUNT(OD.id_order) as ordered_qty FROM ps_product P
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang PL ON P.id_product = PL.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail OD ON P.id_product = OD.product_id
LEFT JOIN ps_orders O ON O.id_order = OD.id_order
WHERE O.valid = 1 AND O.`date_add`  >  '2017-03-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY P.reference, PL.`name`, OD.id_order
ORDER BY ordered_qty DESC
```

But it shows some weird data (product names are in incorrect positions etc) and most important - no idea how to show combinations. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT 
OD.`product_id`, 
OD.`product_attribute_id`,
OD.`product_name`,
sum(OD.`product_quantity`) as qty
FROM ps_order_detail OD
WHERE O.valid = 1 AND O.`date_add` > '2017-03-01 00:00:00'
LEFT JOIN ps_orders O ON O.id_order = OD.id_order
GROUP BY OD.`product_id`, OD.`product_attribute_id`
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

Comment: I added WHERE O.valid = 1 AND O.`date_add`  >  '2017-03-01 00:00:00' and seems to do exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KubaA.please consider marking answer as solved. Thanks